# Relatório Jasper não é gerado em servidor de produção

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat, jasper-reports

um problema no uso do `JasperReports`.

Criei uma classe para gerar os relatórios, a partir de alguns parâmetros. Ele por dentro do Eclipse gera normalmente, mas quando exporto o `WAR` e coloco em produção, ele não faz nada.

No primeiro momento, notei que havia um detalhe - ele não encontrava o arquivo por usar o %20 no lugar dos espaços no caminho do relatório, pelo que notei no log do Tomcat, que tinha dado um `FileNotFoundException`. Daí utilizei o `URLDecoder.decode` para resolver isto, e ele não retorna mais o `FileNotFoundException`, mas continua sem gerar o relatório fora do Eclipse.

Alguém passou por algo parecido?

```
public void imprimir(String arquivo, String nmTitulo,String nmParams, String nmParamsSegunda, List<?> dados) throws Exception{      
JasperReport report = null;
try{
    String caminhoRelatorio = this.getPathToReportPackage() + arquivo+".jrxml";
    System.out.println("porCentoVinte:"+caminhoRelatorio);          
    caminhoRelatorio=URLDecoder.decode(caminhoRelatorio,"UTF-8");           
    System.out.println("porCentoVinte:"+caminhoRelatorio);
    report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(caminhoRelatorio);          

    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    VsecUsuario usr = (VsecUsuario) session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");               
    String nmUsuario = usr.getNmUsuario();
    String nmEmpresa = new Fncts().nmEmpresa();

    Map relParams = new HashMap();
    relParams.put("pNmTitulo",          nmTitulo);
    relParams.put("pNmEmpresa",         nmEmpresa);
    relParams.put("pNmRelParam",        nmParams);
    relParams.put("pNmRelParamSegunda", nmParamsSegunda);
    relParams.put("pUsuarioSistema",    nmUsuario);

    JasperPrint pronto = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, relParams, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados));
    JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer( pronto , false );                
    viewer.setVisible(true);   
}catch(Exception e){
    new Fncts().aviso(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

[image: Aqui são os arquivos que estão na lib do TomCat]

E aqui o log

```
porCentoVinte:/D:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%206.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/classes/br/com/virtus/jasper/reembolso.jrxml
porCentoVinte:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/classes/br/com/virtus/jasper/reembolso.jrxml
porCentoVinte:D:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%206.0\webapps\SGC\WEB-INF\classes\br\com\virtus\jasper\extratocartao.jrxml
porCentoVinte:D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\SGC\WEB-INF\classes\br\com\virtus\jasper\extratocartao.jrxml
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:12.003--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--Begin undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 6
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:12.003--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--End undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 5
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:12.003--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--Begin undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 5
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:12.003--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--End undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 4
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:12.003--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--Begin undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 4
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:12.003--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--End undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 3
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 3
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 4
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 4
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 4
----TESTE DE BUSCA POR CÓDIGO----
[EL Finer]: connection: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--client acquired: 8519566
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--ClientSession(8519566)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 11594463
[EL Finest]: query: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--UnitOfWork(11594463)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="readFiliai" referenceClass=Filiai sql="SELECT CD_FILIAL, CD_ARQ_ENVIO, CD_ARQ_RETORNO, CD_CEP_ENDERECO_FILIAL, CD_CNPJ, CD_DDD_FILIAL, CD_FAX_FILIAL, CD_IE_FILIAL, CD_IM_FILIAL, CD_LOCAL_COBRANCA, CD_NUMERO_ENDERECO_FILIAL, CD_OCORR_DEPOSITO_CHEQUE, CD_SERIE_NOTA_FISCAL, CD_TELEFONE_FILIAL, CD_ULTIMA_NF_FILIAL, CD_ULTIMO_PEDIDO_COMPRA, DONE, DTL, NM_BAIRRO_ENDERECO_FILIAL, NM_CIDADE_FILIAL, NM_COMPL_ENDERECO_FILIAL, NM_ENDERECO_FILIAL, NM_FILIAL, PC_ISS, PC_MAXIMO_FRETE_FILIAL, PC_MULTA_FILIAL, QT_DIAS_CARENCIA_FILIAL, SG_UF FROM FILIAIS WHERE (CD_FILIAL = ?)")
[EL Finest]: transaction: 2015-05-14 16:21:13.581--UnitOfWork(11594463)--Thread(Thread[http-8081-7,5,main])--Register the existing object br.com.virtus.sgc.model.Filiai@87208fa3
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:14.19--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--Begin undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 4
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2015-05-14 16:21:14.19--ServerSession(14536956)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--End undeploying Persistence Unit SGCProjectJPA; session file:/D:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/SGC/WEB-INF/lib/SGCProjectJPA.jar_SGCProjectJPA; state Deployed; factoryCount 3
```

Comment: não tem stacktrace de erro?

Comment: No log não tem nenhuma mensagem... Não estou na máquina no momento, mas assim que tiver mostro. Não há nenhum erro no log, e executa normalmente ao depurar no eclipse. E isto que me intriga.

Comment: Verificou o classpath do servidor?

Comment: @AlexandreStrevenski
O Classpath seria a pasta lib do Tomcat? 
Se for, eu verifiquei, vou adicionar algumas informações.

Comment: Estava com o mesmo problema, consegui corrigir, era a fonte do Jasper.
Se não for isso tenta dar um tail(se for linux) no log e tentar executar novamente pra ver o log certinho e tempo real em produção

Comment: Ao invés de usar o caminho para o relatório, compile o *input stream* dele, recuperado do *classpath*, algo como `InputStream is = SuaClasse.class.getResourceAsStream("/br/com/virtus/jasper/reembolso.jrxml"); JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);`